# Which is more recommended, SQL in the program or in database in stored procedures?

Tags: sql, database

There is any recommendation where is the better place to store the SQL codes?

Supposing two types of SQL queries (CRUD commands and Bussiness queries),  where is better, more recommended and more used place to store the SQL, inside the application or in database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a religious question.

My preference (today):

- for CRUD; use code
- for complex set theory type of analysis; use Stored Procedures

But only if your SQL is under source control.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an ORM system like Hibernate, NHibernate, Entity Framework, etc.  It's best because you avoid a lot of plumbing and you can keep "object queries" in your business code (filters etc), without putting actual SQL in your business code.